# Avoiding duplicate items in a comma-separated list of two-letter words

Tags: swift, regex, string, validation

I need to write a regex which allows a group of 2 chars only once. This is my current regex :

`^([A-Z]{2},)*([A-Z]{2}){1}$`

This allows me to validate something like this :

```
AL,RA,IS,GD
AL
AL,RA
```

The problem is that it validates also `AL,AL` and `AL,RA,AL`.

**EDIT**

Here there are more details.

What is allowed:

```
AL,RA,GD
AL
AL,RA
AL,IS,GD
```

What it shouldn't be allowed:

```
AL,RA,AL
AL,AL
AL,RA,RA
AL,IS,AL
IS,IS,AL
IS,GD,GD
IS,GD,IS
```

I need that every group of two characters appears only once in the sequence.

Comment: Pleas provide some examples of what is acceptable and what is not, and why.

Comment: @Ridcully I've added more details.

Comment: i think this example is not clear with your request.

Comment: @TheGridLock I think now it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this expression:

```
/^(?:,?(\b\w{2}\b)(?!.*\1))+$/gm
```

I have no knowledge of swift, so take it with a grain of salt. The idea is basically to only match a whole line while making sure that no single matched group occurs at a later point in the line.

Comment: Agree but it seems that this is not a request from him, he wants to verify that the string only contains unique 2char combine. such as `AL,IS,GD` but not `AL,IS,AL`

Comment: @TheGridLock That's actually what the expression does. As long as there are fixed delimiters (like beginning and end of a line as in this instance), you should be able to test that with lookarounds.

Comment: I agree it matches but the problem is not there, how it is detected `AL,IS,AL` contains dulicates .if you not match all then count?

Comment: You don't have to count, all you have to do is capture one group and then make sure that this current group is not repeated on the same line. You start this at the beginning of the line and repeat it for every other group until the end of the line is reached. If you now get a match for the line, it must be consisting of unique groups. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: maybe I figured out how it works, you enlightened me a bit. thank you!

Comment: You could possibly get into performance problems when you have several .* quantifiers in your expression which could in principle match the same string, simply because the engine will try a lot more permutations in order to get a match. With matching within a single line and a single 'open' .* group that should not be much of a problem, unless the line is gigantic. I'm not sure whether this addresses your question. / Edit: Alright, thank you for asking; cheers. :)

Comment: Hi, I find the regex quite interesting so I follow the questions here.

Comment: This would match `,AL,RA,GD` (leading comma).

Comment: @Booboo You're right. As with a number of other things, that's a concession to readability and should be result-neutral with respect to the problem as posed in the question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's shorten your pattern. It can be easily achieved since the length of each comma-separated item is fixed and the list items are only made up of uppercase ASCII letters. So, your pattern can be written as `^(?:[A-Z]{2}(?:,\b)?)+$`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5Jmx0/1).

Now, you need to add a negative lookahead that will check the string for any repeating two-letter sequence at any distance from the start of string, and within any distance between each. Use

```
^(?!.*\b([A-Z]{2})\b.*\b\1\b)(?:[A-Z]{2}(?:,\b)?)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5Jmx0/2)

Possible implementation in **Swift**:

```
func isValidInput(Input:String) -> Bool {
    return Input.range(of: #"^(?!.*\b([A-Z]{2})\b.*\b\1\b)(?:[A-Z]{2}(?:,\b)?)+$"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil
}

print(isValidInput(Input:"AL,RA,GD")) // true
print(isValidInput(Input:"AL,RA,AL")) // false
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\b([A-Z]{2})\b.*\b\1\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\b([A-Z]{2})\b` - a two-letter word as a whole word
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\b\1\b` - the same whole word as in Group 1. **NOTE**: The word boundaries here are not necessary in the current scenario where the word length is fixed, it is two, but if you do not know the word length, and you have `[A-Z]+`, you will need the word boundaries, or other boundaries depending on the situation
- `(?:[A-Z]{2}(?:,\b)?)+`  - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `[A-Z]{2}` - two uppercase ASCII letters
  - `(?:,\b)?` - an optional sequence: `,` only if followed with a word char: letter, digit or `_`. This guarantees that `,` won't be allowed at the end of the string
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: In the first regex, `^(?:[A-Z]{2}(?:,\b)?)+$`, is the `\b` really required?

Comment: @Booboo I explained it, yes, or it would be possible to use `,` at the end of the string.

Comment: I missed that explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I learned a few things from your answer: including the use of word breaks here is preferable to requiring a string to be preceded by the beginning of the line or a comma (and followed by...) and enforcing the content of the string by matching the string rather than doing that separately in a positive lookahead and later matching the string with `.*`. That may be obvious but much of this is new to me...

Comment: ...It appears you made the same assumption as I initially did, that all strings of uc letters are of length 2. (See the comments on my answer.) You do not match `"L,RA,ST"`, for example. Could you address that by merely changing `(?:[A-Z]{2}(?:,\b)?)+` to `(?:[A-Z]+(?:,\b)?)+`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, all `[A-Z]{2}` to `[A-Z]+`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5Jmx0/3).

Comment: I think you need to move `"L,RA,ST,L"` to the no-match category. My understanding is that that should be a match, however, in view of the OP's last sentence (which may have been added only recently, but that was my understanding before), that only pairs can't appear twice, regardless of whether strings of length other than 2 may be present. That's why I asked about just changing the one non-capture group.

Comment: `L,RA,ST,L` should not match because `L` is repeated, that is why I added it to the demo.

Comment: I believe `L,RA,ST,L` should match because no 2-char string is repeated. In any event, I was merely pointing out that while that string doesn't match your revised regex, you listed that string in the "what is allowed" category at your link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead with a back-reference:

```
^(?!.*([A-Z]{2}).*\1).*
```

if, as in the all the examples in the question, it is known that the string contains only comma-separated pairs of capital letters. I will relax that assumption later in my answer.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c2LeNZ/1/)

The regex performs the following operations:

```
^             # match beginning of line
(?!           # begin negative lookahead
  .*          # match 0+ characters (1+ OK)
  ([A-Z]{2})  # match 2 uppercase letters in capture group 1
  .*          # match 0+ characters (1+ OK)
  \1          # match the contents of capture group 1
)             # end negative lookahead
.*            # match 0+ characters (the entire string)
```

Suppose now that one or more capital letters may appear between each pair of commas, or before the first comma or after the last comma, but it is only strings of two letters that cannot be repeated. Moreover, I assume the regex must confirm the regex has the desired form. Then the following regex could be used:

```
^(?=[A-Z]+(?:,[A-Z]+)*$)(?!.*(?:^|,)([A-Z]{2}),(?:.*,)?\1(?:,|$)).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c2LeNZ/1/)

The regex performs the following operations:

```
^             # match beginning of line
(?=           # begin pos lookahead
  [A-Z]+      # match 1+ uc letters
  (?:,[A-Z]+) # match ',' then by 1+ uc letters in a non-cap grp
  *           # execute the non-cap grp 0+ times
  $           # match the end of the line
)             # end pos lookahead
(?!           # begin neg lookahead
  .*          # match 0+ chars
  (?:^|,)     # match beginning of line or ','
  ([A-Z]{2})  # match 2 uc letters in cap grp 1
  ,           # match ','
  (?:.*,)     # match 0+ chars, then ',' in non-cap group
  ?           # optionally match non-cap grp
  \1          # match the contents of cap grp 1
  (?:,|$)     # match ',' or end of line
)             # end neg lookahead
.*            # match 0+ chars (entire string)
```

If there is no need check that the string contains only comma-separated strings of one or more upper case letters the postive lookahead at the beginning can be removed.

Comment: It seems to match: `D` and  `DEF` and `D,` etc.

Comment: @Booboo, I had assumed it was known that the string contained only pairs of letters separated by commas, as that is the case with all the examples presented. I will to modify my regex to remove that assumption.

Comment: Maybe you assumption is reasonable. Don't change anything for my benefit.

Comment: @Booboo, I amended my answer.